# Count active users based on logins last 90 days

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a query that will result in a list showing how many active users we have month by month. We define an active users as a user that have been logged in in the last 90 days.

I can easily define the number of active users we have right now by this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id) FROM login_table
WHERE login_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(login_date, INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND NOW())
```

My problem comes when I have to count the amount of users we have month by month
Here i have to count one single login several times.

If I have a user that login at 10 of January, and never login again, this user should count as an active user in the following months: January, February, March and April, even though I only have one registration of the user

Example data:

```
login_date | user_id
2015-01-01 | 1
2015-02-10 | 1
2015-02-11 | 2
2015-02-13 | 1
2015-03-19 | 1
```

This should result in something like this:

```
Date    | Active users
2015-01 | 1 
2015-02 | 2
2015-03 | 2 
2015-04 | 2 
2015-05 | 2 
2015-06 | 1 
2015-07 | 0 
2015-08 | 0
```

Is there anyway of doing a count like that?

Comment: Um, that query would result in a syntax error. And consider handling the logic of missing months in application-level code.

Comment: Do you have a calendar table? Things would be much easier if you had one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems like this are easier to solve, if you have a calendar table with all the dates you need. If you don't have such a table you can create it with a query like this:

```sql
create table `calendar` (
    `date` DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`date`)
)  
    select DATE_ADD('1900-01-01',INTERVAL t4.c*10000 + t3.c*1000 + t2.c*100 + t1.c*10 + t0.c DAY) as `date`
    from 
    (select 0 c union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t0,
    (select 0 c union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t1,
    (select 0 c union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t2,
    (select 0 c union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t3,
    (select 0 c union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t4
```

That will create a table with dates from 1900-01-01 to 2173-10-15 (100K days) and consume only about 2.5 MB. You can adjust it to your needs.

Using the caledar table you can get three-month-ranges:

```sql
select 
    DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(c.date, INTERVAL 1 day), '%Y-%m') as month,
    date_sub(c.date, INTERVAL 3 month) as first_day,
    date_sub(c.date, INTERVAL 1 day)   as last_day
from calendar c
where day(c.date) = 1
  and c.date between '2015-02-01' and '2015-09-01'
```

Result:

```sql
| month   | first_day  | last_day   |
| 2015-01 | 2014-11-01 | 2015-01-31 |
| 2015-02 | 2014-12-01 | 2015-02-28 |
| 2015-03 | 2015-01-01 | 2015-03-31 |
| 2015-04 | 2015-02-01 | 2015-04-30 |
| 2015-05 | 2015-03-01 | 2015-05-31 |
| 2015-06 | 2015-04-01 | 2015-06-30 |
| 2015-07 | 2015-05-01 | 2015-07-31 |
| 2015-08 | 2015-06-01 | 2015-08-31 |
```

Adjust it, if you really want to use something like 90 days intervals.

Now it's a simple left join with the login table to get what you want:

```sql
select i.month as `Date`, count(distinct l.user_id) as `Active users`
from (
    select 
        date_format(date_sub(c.date, interval 1 day), '%Y-%m') as month,
        date_sub(c.date, interval 3 month) as first_day,
        date_sub(c.date, interval 1 day)   as last_day
    from calendar c
    where day(c.date) = 1
      and c.date between '2015-02-01' and '2015-09-01'
) i
left join login_table l on l.login_date between i.first_day and i.last_day
group by i.month
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1bb0/3

Answer (score 2):

Can you use:

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(login_date,'%Y %m') as date, ....
....    
Group by DATE_FORMAT(login_date,'%Y %m')
```

Comment: Yes and no, its good to define that I only wants to look at the month, but i can not use it to define that a login has to be counted in several months. IE a user who only login in Januray, and never login again, have to count as an active user in both Januray, Feburary March and April, not only in Janurary

Answer (score 2):

You can build an in-line tally table containing *all* the required month/year value pairs. Then `LEFT JOIN` your table to this table and `GROUP BY` to get the required result:

```
SELECT CONCAT(months.m, '-', years.y) AS 'date', 
       COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) AS 'users_count'
FROM (
   SELECT '01' AS m UNION ALL SELECT '02' UNION ALL SELECT '03' UNION ALL 
   SELECT '04' UNION ALL SELECT '05' UNION ALL SELECT '06' UNION ALL 
   SELECT '07' UNION ALL SELECT '08' UNION ALL SELECT '09' UNION ALL 
   SELECT '10' UNION ALL SELECT '11' UNION ALL SELECT '12') AS months
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT '2015' AS y UNION ALL SELECT '2016') AS years
LEFT JOIN login_table AS lt
   ON DATE_FORMAT(lt.login_date, '%d-%Y') = CONCAT(months.m, '-', years.y)
GROUP BY CONCAT(months.m, '-', years.y)
```

The above query is suitable for producing a report for all the months from years 2015/2016. You can edit the tally table as you wish in order to adapt it to your actual requirement.

**Edit:**

You need correlation if you want to count *active* users in *rolling* 3 month intervals:

```
SELECT CONCAT(months.m, '-', years.y) AS 'date', 
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) 
        FROM login_table
        WHERE login_date BETWEEN CONCAT(years.y, '-', months.m, '-01') AND 
                                 DATE_ADD(CONCAT(years.y, '-', months.m, '-01'), INTERVAL 90 DAY))
FROM (
   SELECT '01' AS m UNION ALL SELECT '02' UNION ALL SELECT '03' UNION ALL 
   SELECT '04' UNION ALL SELECT '05' UNION ALL SELECT '06' UNION ALL 
   SELECT '07' UNION ALL SELECT '08' UNION ALL SELECT '09' UNION ALL 
   SELECT '10' UNION ALL SELECT '11' UNION ALL SELECT '12') AS months
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT '2015' AS y UNION ALL SELECT '2016') AS years
LEFT JOIN login_table AS lt
   ON DATE_FORMAT(lt.login_date, '%d-%Y') = CONCAT(months.m, '-', years.y)
GROUP BY CONCAT(months.m, '-', years.y)
```

Answer (score 0):

and by using the method MONTH()?

something like this:

```
SELECT MONTH(login-date) as perMonth, COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) from login_table GROUP BY MONTH(login-date)
```

Comment: That will only give me the result for each month, the problem is that a login has to be counted in several months, so a that user who only login in Januray, and never login again, have to count as an active user in both Januray, Feburary March and April, not only in Janurary

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Date_format(login_date, '%Y-%m-%01') as mymonth, count(user_id) as totalusers 
FROM login_table
WHERE login_date >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)
Group by Date_format(login_date, '%Y-%m-%01')
```

Here is info about date_format function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(login_date, "%Y-%m"), COUNT(user_id)
FROM login_table
WHERE login_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(login_date, INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND NOW()
GROUP BY login_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple and stupid solution is to copy the `login_table` six times adding 15 days to the `login_date` each time. This way we can ensure that every login is duplicated at least once in every month within the following 90 days. Then we can group by year and moth to count active users.

```sql
select 
    date_format(login_date, "%Y-%m") as `Date`,
    count(distinct l.user_id) as `Active users`
from (
    select l.user_id, l.login_date from login_table l
    union all select l.user_id, date_add(l.login_date, interval 15 day) from login_table l
    union all select l.user_id, date_add(l.login_date, interval 30 day) from login_table l
    union all select l.user_id, date_add(l.login_date, interval 45 day) from login_table l
    union all select l.user_id, date_add(l.login_date, interval 60 day) from login_table l
    union all select l.user_id, date_add(l.login_date, interval 75 day) from login_table l
    union all select l.user_id, date_add(l.login_date, interval 90 day) from login_table l
) l
group by date_format(login_date, "%Y-%m")
```